# A module with non-zero dual that does not canonically embed in its bidual

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'd like to find a ring $A$ and an $A$-module $E$ such that $E^*\neq\{0\}$ and the canonical mapping of $E$ into $E^{**}$ is not injective.

As a hint (it's an exercise in Bourbaki's Algebra) I have "consider a module containing an element whose annihilator contains an element which is not a divisor of zero".

I'm not sure how the hint is supposed to help: there are $\mathbf{Z}$-modules with the property from the hint ($\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$), but their dual is zero. Unfortunately, my repertoire of interesting modules is very limited.

Can somebody help me along? Another hint or an example without proof would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that forming duals is additive (i.e. is compatible with taking direct sums).  So try combining an example of a module with a non-zero dual and a module with zero dual via a direct sum.

Comment: Ah, so the dual of the $\mathbf{Z}$-module $\mathbf{Q}\oplus\mathbf{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$ and $(1,0)$ lies in the kernel of the canonical mapping. Thank you very much!